# does ldap works in a offline environment?

Tags: ldap, offline

Does LDAP server & phpldapadmin works in an offline environment?
I've successfully tested on a online environment it's works, however there is some issue encounter after i removed the internet connection.

Trying to use LDAP address book for outlook

any help?

Comment: Define 'some issue encounter'. An LDAP server can be standalone or totally dependent on upstream servers. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have a online environment & a offline environment.
both using the same way to setup. but the offline environment without internet can't link up to phpldapadmin to setup users.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends what you are trying to achieve and where is your LDAP server. But generally, LDAP directory servers are centralized, and an offline environment will not be able to access it.

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie in LDAP. Still trying to figure it out. The purpose of using LDAP is for updating of outlook address book. Is there any way to have it work in a offline environment?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in local network or offline, When you test your solution in local environment. When you publish your solution deploy in server then run on test production link it will works